# Unable to copy and paste from Google Calendar App

Tags: google-calendar

I have found that I cannot copy and paste from the Google Calendar app.  I use the calendar to alert me for bill payments, but under 14.04, I cannot copy information from the calendar window.  And, URLs that work as links in other OSes (Windows, for instance) do not work in 14.04's Calendar App, and I cannot copy the URL to a browser, either.  Does anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Google Calendar app? you mean chrome app for Google calendar? Or are you referring to Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in launchpad. I am experiencing the same problem - and it is present for all application based on the `webbrowser-app` package i am using in ubuntu 14.04.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webbrowser-app/+bug/1264493

Therefore it is much better to use applications in chrome or chromium. These can also be launched as separate applications and can be present in your menu as standalone programs.
(If you do not have chrome or chromium you can search for chromium in the Ubuntu Software Center and install it from there)

To install the google calendar app in chrome/chromium:

- Open your chrome / chromium browser
- Click on the apps tab
- Click on web store
- Search for google calendar
- Install it by pressing the "Free" button

Now you have the application installed. This guide is to make a standalone application for it:

- Back in the Apps tab you see now that you have Google Calendar
- Right click the application to see the context menu
- Click create shortcut - and select applications menu

The application will now be searchable from your unity dash, and you can move it to your menu if you like.
Note that the names and icons for the old calendar application is somewhat similar so be sure to select the right one. The Chrome/Chromium one is called `Google Calendar` and the webbrowser based is called `GoogleCalendar` without a space.

This procedure also works for gmail, google docs and other google applications.

Good luck.